# How to get data from Foreign key related tables?Can I use select_related or prefetch_related for getting the data from below tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

How can I query these three tables to get list of all users, tasks  and project name for a project.How to get them in a single query set?
Am using Django RestFramework for the serializing the data.

A project can have n-users and n-tasks

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)

class Subtask(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name = "project_tasks")

class Users(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name = "project_user")
```

Answer (score 2):

`prefetch_related` is for reverse relationships, which is what you have here from Project to both Subtask and User. So:

```
Project.objects.get(name=whatever).prefetch_related('project_tasks', 'project_users')
```

(Note you should be consistent with naming; the relationship is one to many so you should use a plural for the related_name. Similarly, model class names should be singular as an instance reflects one item, so the class should be User.)

Comment: am not able to get the users or tasks data. could you tell me how we can get it from the returned result set

Comment: Exactly as you would if you weren't using prefetch_related: `my_project.project_tasks.all()`, etc.

Comment: But when try like this queryData.project_tasks.task_name it says 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'task_name'

Comment: Yes. It doesn't have that attribute. Because `project_tasks` is a *queryset* representing several tasks. Because that is what a one-to-many relationship is.

Comment: Oh okay, then how can I get the 'task_name' and 'user_name' from the queryset?

Comment: Well, again, in exactly the same way as you would from any other queryset. I am puzzled by your difficulty here. You need to iterate through via `my_project.project_tasks.all()` as I showed above, and output those attributes for each one. Once again, this has nothing at all to do with prefetch_related.